# qemu/KVM iptables port forwarding

Tags: centos, iptables, kvm, qemu

After dozens of articles, blob, tutorials and even answered questions here on stackoverflow, I'm still stuck on my problem: how to setup port forwarding from host to guests VMs.

First: sorry for my poor english level, I'll try to be as clear as possible

Second: I'm absolute newbe in networking, but I've to setup this server for my collegues

We've a public hosted Centos 7 server on which we want set up 3 KVM VMs to serve multiple test environment for our web software. My idea was to assign a range of ports to be forwarded to each VM, let's say ports 10001:19999 forwarded to 1:9999 of the VM 1, ports 20001:29999 forwarded to 1:9999 of the VM 2 and so on.

I've tried a lot of solution but none worked. Here is my current set up:

```
#> ifconfig

eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xx.xxx.xx.xxx  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast xx.xxx.xx.255
        ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10190055  bytes 644136763 (614.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 338010  bytes 27222247 (25.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x92b00000-92bfffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2283  bytes 4633913 (4.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2283  bytes 4633913 (4.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4448  bytes 566487 (553.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3374  bytes 1243921 (1.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 268  bytes 23314 (22.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2071  bytes 114034 (111.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
#> cat /etc/sysctl.conf

# sysctl settings are defined through files in
# /usr/lib/sysctl.d/, /run/sysctl.d/, and /etc/sysctl.d/.
#
# Vendors settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/.
# To override a whole file, create a new file with the same in
# /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there. To override
# only specific settings, add a file with a lexically later
# name in /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there.
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

---

```
#> cat /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu

#!/bin/bash

v=$(/sbin/iptables -L FORWARD -n -v | /usr/bin/grep 192.168.122.0/24 | /usr/bin/wc -l)
# avoid duplicate as this hook get called for each VM
[ $v -lt 1 ] && /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD 1 -o virbr0 -m state -s xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32 -d 192.168.122.0/24 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

update(){

  if [ "${2}" = "stopped" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING 1 -d $GUEST_IP -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT -j DNAT --to-destination $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT -m comment --comment "$1 VM port forwarding"
  fi
  if [ "${2}" = "start" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -d $GUEST_IP -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT -j DNAT --to-destination $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT -m comment --comment "$1 VM port forwarding"
  fi

}

GUEST_PORT=1-9999

if [ "${1}" = "VM1" ]; then
   GUEST_IP=192.168.122.101
   HOST_PORT=10001:19999
elif [ "${1}" = "VM2" ]; then
   GUEST_IP=192.168.122.102
   HOST_PORT=20001:29999
fi

update $1 $2
```

---

```
#>virsh net-edit default

<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>0db10b13-21c6-45c3-a891-ec46509b2121</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
      <host mac='bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:01' name='VM1' ip='192.168.122.101'/>
      <host mac='bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:02' name='VM2' ip='192.168.122.102'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

The qemu hook seems to work fine and iptables rules are as I would aspect

```
#> iptables -L FORWARD -nv --line-number

num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  xx.xxx.xx.xxx        192.168.122.0/24     state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2      185 13612 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4      186 13704 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
5        0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
6        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  xx.xxx.xx.xxx        192.168.122.0/24     state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
7        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

#> iptables -t nat -L -n -v

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 25580 packets, 2244K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.101      tcp dpts:10001:19999 /* VM1 port forwarding */ to:192.168.122.101:1-9999

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 774 packets, 46800 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 578 packets, 44429 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 578 packets, 44429 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN      all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     224.0.0.0/24
    0     0 RETURN      all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255
    4   240 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
  159 12084 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
```

but when I try to reach my VM via ssh, let's say VM1 from my pc,

```
ssh root@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:10022
```

it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Multiple different problems

Reading this schematic will help understand the order of operations happening to a packet for the explanations below:

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

### `filter/FORWARD`: properly allow DNAT-ed packets

Currently this rule:

> ```
> ... /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD 1 -o virbr0 -m state -s xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32 -d 192.168.122.0/24 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> ```

will never match: when forwarded (routed) a packet will never have a source of the host's address, or it would be emitted by the host but then it wouldn't traverse PREROUTING hooks (but OUTPUT). `nat/PREROUTING` changes the destination, not the source.

To allow remote access either specify one rule per allowed remote source (replace host's xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32 with an allowed remote client yy.yyy.yy.yyy 's address) or don't specify any source to allow any remote client:

```
/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD 1 -o virbr0 -d 192.168.122.0/24 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

If one wants to match specifically that the packet first reached the destination xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32 (useful for example for an host having multiple public addresses and one dedicated to this role) and was then translated to 192.168.122.0/24 it's still possible with the `conntrack` match (which supersedes OP's `state` match):

```
/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD 1 -o virbr0 -d 192.168.122.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED --ctorigdst xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32  -j ACCEPT
```

There are other possibilities, the easiest being simply to accept any packet part of a flow having undergone any DNAT transformation issued in a previous rule, since such DNAT is useful only when the flow is then accepted:

```
/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
```

### `nat/PREROUTING`: original destination is not the VM's address

Since the VMs are not reachable directly, a client won't attempt to connect to 192.168.122.101:10022. If it could reach 192.168.122.101 directly it could simply then connect to 192.168.122.101:22 and this question would not have been asked.

The client will connect to the host's single public IP (or even an alternate public IP). The host's *iptables* rules then translates ports to IPs and ports. So if the host has xx.xxx.xx.xxx address, the `nat/PREROUTING` rule must not try to match the IP destination of the VM but try to match the IP destination of the host. Once this happened `filter/FORWARD` will see the final destination (as described in previous point).

In the end don't use:

> ```
> /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -d $GUEST_IP -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT -j DNAT --to-destination $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT -m comment --comment "$1 VM port forwarding"
> ```

But for example this (also specifying the incoming interface to avoid complications):

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eno2 -d xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32 -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT -j DNAT --to-destination $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT -m comment --comment "$1 VM port forwarding"
```

### nat/OUTPUT versus nat/PREROUTING

Locally emitted packets from the host are not handled the same as forwarded (routed) packets.

OP's additional rules are in `nat/PREROUTING`. `PREROUTING` happens when a packet is received (and before the routing decision). Specifically `nat/PREROUTING` happens only for the *first* packet of a connection flow (as all *nat* hooks), and only when this first packet has been received rather than emitted.

When tried from a *remote* system (not the *libvirtd* host), OP's rule should trigger correctly. Tests should always be done like the final use case: if it's for remote access, test should be from remote (thsi might have been the case, but OP didn't state it).

When testing from the host this is different because the *first* packet is never a received packet but it's an emitted packet: it won't traverse `PREROUTING`. Then the VM's reply which is not anymore the first packet in a flow (so is not in *conntrack* state `NEW` anymore), like above, skips all of this because NAT is completely handled by Netfilter with the resulting *conntrack* entry. The previous schematic states it:

> "NAT" table only consulted for "NEW" connections

So in the host case, this `nat/PREROUTING` alteration from previous point:

> ```
> /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eno2 -d xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32 -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT -j DNAT --to-destination $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT -m comment --comment "$1 VM port forwarding"
> ```

will never trigger: the alteration's effect isn't yet available so the destination is still xx.xxx.xx.xxx. That's this very rule that will change it.

A similar setup done in `nat/PREROUTING` has also to be done in `nat/OUTPUT`:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT 1 -d xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32 -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT -m comment --comment "VM1 port forwarding" -j DNAT --to-destination $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT -m comment --comment "$1 VM port forwarding test from host"
```

which will now match correctly.

On the other hand, host's tcp services on ports 10001-19999 become unreachable from itself when using xx.xxx.xx.xxx instead of for example 127.0.0.1. One could still use a rule where `-d xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32` is replaced with OP's original `$GUEST_IP` since host has direct connectivity, but it won't be very useful except for testing the rulesets.

But anyway in all cases...

### *iptables* can't do static port range mapping

... resulting most likely now in `Connection refused` for almost all attempts and if not, most likely not reaching the intended service on the VM.

> ```
> ... -p tcp --dport 10001:19999 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.101:1-9999
> ```

will not magically subtract 10000 to the port value as a result. It will pick an arbitrary port available (ie: not matching a previous *conntrack* entry) in the 1-9999 range for each different flow. So port 10022 won't be translated to port 22, but to a random value in the range, for example 6456, and it will be different port value at each successive attempt with a new connection.

I have no solution based on *iptables* for this except having to add 9999 rules, one per port. Specifically for port 22, this would work:

```
... -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10022 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.101:22
```

So one really should select a small list of ports and do single port mappings one rule at a time. If VM1 were an HTTP 1.x server, one could use 3 rules, one for port 22, one for port 80 and one for port 443 (but an HTTP reverse proxy on the host might be a better solution).

```
... -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10022 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.101:22
... -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10080 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.101:80
... -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.101:443
```

## Bonus: ways for easier static port range mapping

As a bonus, here are discussions on how to do a static port translation. **Can't be used on CentOS 7** because it lacks required features. But sooner or later ([2024-06-30](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product)) CentOS 7 will have to be replaced so...

### <s>[*ipset*](https://ipset.netfilter.org/)</s>

Can't be used for these two reasons:

- no *ipset* type has two ports in it to map from one port to an other port in addition to an address.
- more importantly, *iptables*' `DNAT` target has no provision to use this subsystem.

### nftables

Tested with *nftables* 1.0.2 and kernel 5.16.x.

This requires recent versions of *nftables* and the kernel. CentOS 7 won't qualify. *nftables* is available since kernel 3.13. CentOS 7 uses kernel 3.10: the mere presence of *nftables* is already a kernel feature backport from Red Hat. Many newer *nftables* features will be missing from the tool and from the kernel.

In particular on older kernels *nftables* and *iptables* (legacy) specifically clash for the NAT hooks, and thus can't be used together for doing NAT (one will be unable to register or be silently ignored), while they can work along together just fine in newer kernels.

The `filter/FORWARD` part and even the generic `MASQUERADE` rule(s) can be kept as is with *iptables*, only NAT dealing with port translation to the VMs has to be done using *nftables*.

- bitwise operations

  This is probably the option having the lowest requirement for *nftables* and kernel versions (but CentOS 7's kernel 3.10 won't be enough).

  *nftables* has more features but still can't do a subtraction so can't subtract 10000 to a tcp port. However it can perform bitwise operations just fine. So instead of allocating a 10000-ports range, if the range is aligned to a multiple of a power of two then such static port mapping is possible. Near the range 10000 one could possibly use 8192 (to reach a total of 65536/8192-1=7 VMs) or 16384 (for a total of 3 VMs).

  Let's use 16384: first range available 16384-32767 (0x4000-0x7fff) with netmask 16383 (0x3fff). Since the port translation is mapping to the first range (0-16383) of the destination port there's no bitwise-or (`|`) to apply in addition to the bitwise-and (`&` below).

  Priority -110 is used to take precedence over *iptables*' priority of -100 for similar hooks. For NAT if *nftables*'s NAT hooks don't match, *iptables*' NAT equivalent hooks still have their chance at matching later, as usual.

  ```
  nft add table rangenat
  nft add chain rangenat prerouting '{ type nat hook prerouting priority -110; }'
  nft add chain rangenat output '{ type nat hook output priority -110; }'
  ```

  and for the first VM:

  ```
  nft add rule rangenat prerouting 'ip daddr xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32 tcp dport 16384-32767 dnat to 192.168.122.101:tcp dport & 0x3fff'
  nft add rule rangenat output 'ip daddr xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32 tcp dport 16384-32767 dnat to 192.168.122.101:tcp dport & 0x3fff'
  ```

  A mockup test with a client with address 203.0.113.11 connecting to the host with address 192.0.2.2 on port 16384+22=16406 as would this command do (OP's syntax is wrong, the port should be specified with a `-p` parameter):

  ```
  ssh -p 16406 root@192.0.2.2
  ```

  results in these *conntrack* entries displayed with `conntrack -E` on the host during the TCP 3-way handshake:

  ```
      [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=203.0.113.11 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=42458 dport=16406 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.122.101 dst=203.0.113.11 sport=22 dport=42458
   [UPDATE] tcp      6 60 SYN_RECV src=203.0.113.11 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=42458 dport=16406 src=192.168.122.101 dst=203.0.113.11 sport=22 dport=42458
   [UPDATE] tcp      6 432000 ESTABLISHED src=203.0.113.11 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=42458 dport=16406 src=192.168.122.101 dst=203.0.113.11 sport=22 dport=42458 [ASSURED]
  ```

  with the reply port src (in 2nd part) showing `sport=22` as intended.
- [maps](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Maps)

  Requires [nftables 0.9.4](https://marc.info/?l=netfilter&m=158575148505527&w=2) for NAT mapping with concatenations (and *typeof* syntax) and kernel 5.6.

  *nftables*' `dnat` statement can use a *map* to assist its alteration (while *iptables*' `DNAT` target can't use *ipset*).

  With the previous skeleton:

  ```
  nft add table rangenat
  nft add chain rangenat prerouting '{ type nat hook prerouting priority -110; }'
  nft add chain rangenat output '{ type nat hook output priority -110; }'
  ```

  Add a map:

  ```
  nft add map rangenat port2ipport '{ typeof tcp dport : ip daddr . tcp dport; }'
  ```

  these generic rules:

  ```
    nft add rule rangenat prerouting 'ip daddr xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32 dnat ip to tcp dport map @port2ipport
    nft add rule rangenat output 'ip daddr xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32 dnat ip to tcp dport map @port2ipport
  ```

  and then anytime later with a loop, it could be populated like this:

  ```
  nft add element rangenat port2ipport '{ 10001: 192.168.122.101 . 1 }'
  ...
  nft add element rangenat port2ipport '{ 10022: 192.168.122.101 . 22 }'
  ...
  nft add element rangenat port2ipport '{ 19999: 192.168.122.101 . 9999 }'
  nft add element rangenat port2ipport '{ 20001: 192.168.122.102 . 1 }'
  ...
  ```

  or just the minimum needed parts together, for example:

  ```
  nft add element rangenat port2ipport '{ 10022: 192.168.122.101 . 22, 10080: 192.168.122.101 . 80, 10443: 192.168.122.101 . 443, 20022: 192.168.122.102 . 22, 30022: 192.168.122.103 . 22 }'
  ```

  As its hashed, the typical lookup time in the *map* is O(1), comparable to the previous bitwise operations based method. Using one rule per port in the simplest way with *iptables* or *nftables* would have O(n) lookup time which could start affecting performance with several thousand rules.

Comment: Men! You just saved my life, or at least saved me from insanity! Thank you so much. As I wrote the current configuration was just one of hundreds I tried, maybe one of the silliest! Your solution works fine for one port in each row, I think I will go with a reverse proxy on the host for the web ports, but just wandering, I found the "range" port setting almost everywhere on blogs about port forwarding, how is it possible!?

Comment: When it's affecting the *source* port (in SNAT or MASQUERADE) it doesn't matter much into what it can be changed. It's only when affecting the *destination* port (DNAT or REDIRECT) that it matters and usually becomes useless. To really split the ports both ways with the VMs (like some ISPs are doing rather than using much worse CGNAT), for egress traffic a single (eg MASQUERADE --to-ports a-b or SNAT --to-source :a-b) rule per VM specifying the source port range is needed rather than 9999 rules when specifying the destination port.

Comment: shifted port range with iptables appears to have been existing for this: [this kernel commit for 4.18](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2eb0f624b709e78ec8e2f4c3412947703db99301) and [this very recent documentation patch submission: 2022-03-30](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/patch/20220331101211.10099-2-phil@nwl.cc/). This would allow to use iptables very easily with `-p tcp --dport 10001:19999 -j DNAT --to :10001-19999/-10000`, but I couldn't manage to make it work. Maybe further documentation'll have examples.